# How can I post controversial material without hurting my professional reputation?

Tags: professionalism

My problem is, that I am a pick-up artist but also a teacher. However, I'd like to share my knowledge on how to meet women via e.g. YouTube.

I do not want to teach how to manipulate women into bed, but how to improve oneself to be less anxious to meet women. How to approach, behave during dates, how to text them. What mistakes one should avoid, etc.

I fear that it would negatively impact my reputation as a school teacher.

How can I share some of my passions in my personal life in a way which does not negatively impact my professional reputation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about navigating the workplace. It's about social media.

Comment: If you are a teacher and you decide to do this, do not use any women in the videos who are in any way close to being underage.

Comment: Hi sparrrkle, I edited your question a bit to make it more on topic here. If I changed your intent too much feel free to [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @JimG. I think "how do I do a controversial hobby without getting fired because of it" is on-topic here.

Comment: There are some jobs that hold a person to different ethical, moral (and legal) standards. In most countries, being a teacher is one of those jobs. The old adage of "if it feels wrong, it probably is" applies here. The 2 areas just don't seem compatible.

Comment: I guess I'll ask the principals/headmasters at our school, if they're fine with it it should be OK. I once let my pupils discuss internet articles about the topic "ten dating mistakes men/women make". It was in 11th grade in Germany. It was great fun. The pupils liked it a lot and many of them showed great psychological insight concerning attraction and so on. Some of the male pupils said that they now realize why they've become "friendzoned" so often.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't advise posting the videos, it probably will harm your career. There are a lot of people with an axe to grind against PUA, as you can probably just by looking at some of the other answers.

I'm not saying there is anything wrong with PUA, it can be seen as manipulation, but then so can taking a woman on a date and buying her dinner. Personally I don't see one as being worse than the other. Unfortunately reason and fairness do not play a part in this. Mob justice is what will cost you your reputation and probably job and you can't reason with a mob, just don't make yourself a target to begin with.

Comment: Sure, I like to buy random people free food just purely out of the kindness of my heart .....

Answer (score 2):

I believe being a teacher is being one of the visible figure of the society. As much as being a mayor, priest, celebrity, etc.
As a visible figure of the society, EVERYTHING public will be connected to your job.

I would suggest therefore to think in term of **public relation** for anything you would do in public (and in a certain extend in private).

To answer your question, with your particular case, I think it's a no go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try concealing your identity, but wearing a mask and using a voice changer would probably degrade anything you tried to creepy.  If you only used a pseudonym parents/students/peers would be readily able to recognize you; with likely disastrous affects to your career.